# Attaching archive to post

Tags: discussion

In a comment to a my question I've been asked to "Please update you question with the something reproducible".

This is quite understandable and I would like to comply, but specifics would not be "just a few lines of code", so I'm unsure about just how to proceed; AFAIK there's no way to upload an "attachment" to a post (correct me if I missed something!).

- should I post inline (possibly monster-post)?
- should I point to some off-site location (possibly disappearing in future)?

Both solutions don't seem right. What's the advised course of action?

Comment: What is that you wish to upload? Will it exceed the 30k character limit for posts?

Comment: Is there any way that you can list steps for others to reproduce an appropriate archive themselves?

Comment: I was about to turn my comment into an answer, but I'm having trouble with the context. I see [one of your recent questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/473615/how-to-setup-qemu-networking-for-web-app-server-on-guest) has a request from mosvy asking for something reproducible, namely: `what servers you ran on the guest, what command exactly you used to connect to localhost:7777`; where does a large archive come in? If there's a lot of output, you might take a first pass at removing innocuous lines; or start with just the top (N) and bottom (N) lines.

Answer (score 2):

You have not missed anything -- there is no way to attach a file to Stack Exchange posts. There is a limit; I could only put my hands on the Answer-body-limit, in the [Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/307535), under **Answering**, saying:

> Maximum of 30000 characters in answer

(If anyone has a better reference, particularly for Questions, please update this post).

Your specific situation had a request for clarification on which systems you ran the command on and what commands you typed to encounter the error. Neither of those should push you into a character limit.

If, however, you do have a large amount of data (e.g. log files) to post, my suggestions would be:

1. start by pasting all (or as much as you can) of it into the Question box
2. format it appropriately (the curly braces, to format it as "code")
3. If it's too large, remove lines that are repeated and insert a command saying "removed repeated lines"
4. If it's still too large, scan for messages that do *not* contain error strings like "fail", "warning", or "error" and consider deleting them.
5. If it's still too large, post the top 20-50 lines and the bottom 20-50 lines, and extend those arbitrary limits if you see *changing* *errors*.